# Mandrill — How to format complex data for handlebars templates

Tags: templates, mandrill

I am trying to send a templated email via Mandrill but am having issues with the templates picking up the data I am sending.

[The docs](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-Dynamic-Content) say that I need to convert my data to arrays of `[{ name: 'propertyName', content: 'the content' }]`

The example they give is as follows

Data

```
"global_merge_vars": [
  {
    "name": "user_name",
    "content": "Mandrill_User1"
  }
]
```

Template

```
<p>Thanks for registering! Your username is {{user_name}}.</p>
```

Result

```
<p>Thanks for registering! Your username is Mandrill_User1.</p>
```

In my case the data is more complex.

I have something like

```
{
  "firstname": "Tyler",
  "lastname": "Durden",
  "fullname": "Tyler Durden",
  "email": "tyler.durden@testy.tes",
  "company": {
    "name": "Company 1",
    "role": {
      "slug": "supplier",
      "name": "Supplier"
    }
  }
}
```

which I convert to `name`:`content` pairs as follows, to send as the `global_merge_vars`

```
[
   { name: 'firstname', content: 'Tyler' },
  { name: 'lastname', content: 'Durden' },
  { name: 'fullname', content: 'Tyler Durden' },
  { name: 'email', content: 'tyler.durden@testy.tes' },
  {
    name: 'company',
    content: [
      { name: 'name', content: 'Company 1' },
      {
        name: 'role',
        content: [
          { name: 'slug', content: 'supplier' },
          { name: 'name', content: 'Supplier' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And my template is

Subject

```
Dear {{user.firstname}} {{company.name}} has been approved.
```

Body

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Dear {{user.firstname}},</p>
    <p>Your company {{company.name}} has been approved.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the result is

Subject

Dear has been approved.

Body

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Dear ,</p>
    <p>Your company  has been approved.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have set up Mandrill to use `handlebars` as its template language.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and error I have worked this out.  It turns out only the *top level* object needs to be turned into a `name`, `content` pair. The lower order object structure can stay as a normal JSON object.

So

```
{
  "name": "user"
  "content": {
    "firstname": "Tyler",
    "lastname": "Durden",
    "fullname": "Tyler Durden",
    "email": "tyler.durden@testy.tes",
    "company": {
      "name": "Company 1",
      "role": {
        "slug": "supplier",
        "name": "Supplier"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with template subject: `Hello {{user.firstname}}`

and body

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Dear {{user.firstname}},</p>
    <p>Your company {{user.company.name}} has been approved.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Works fine.

The docs were a bit misleading in this regard.

Comment: You beat me to the answer. :) Each merge tag needs to be of that format, but the content can be a JSON object.